# How do I do this Pivot (transpose)

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

Working in SQL-Server, I have the below table:

```
    visit    temperature    treatment    denom    num    pct
    A        <38°C          1            101      98     97.0
    A        38.0-38.4°C    1            103      2      1.9
    A        38.5-38.9°C    1            100      1      1.0
    A        <38°C          2            100      97     97.0
    A        38.0-38.4°C    2            100      1      1.0
    A        38.5-38.9°C    2            102      4      3.9
    B        <38°C          1            101      89     88.1
    B        38.0-38.4°C    1            100      2      2.0
    B        38.5-38.9°C    1            105      1      1.0
    B        <38°C          2            104      96     96.4
    B        38.0-38.4°C    2            104      5      1.8
    B        38.5-38.9°C    2            100      3      3.0
```

What should be done to make the table look like this?:

```
    visit    temperature    name         _1       _2
    A        <38°C          denom        101.0    100.0
    A        <38°C          num          98.0     97.0
    A        <38°C          pct          97.0     97.0
    A        38.0-38.4°C    denom        103.0    100.0
    A        38.0-38.4°C    num          2.0      1.0
    A        38.0-38.4°C    pct          1.9      1.0
    A        38.5-38.9°C    denom        100.0    102.0
    A        38.5-38.9°C    num          1.0      4.0
    A        38.5-38.9°C    pct          1.0      3.9
    B        <38°C          denom        101.0    104.0
    B        <38°C          num          89.0     96.0
    B        <38°C          pct          88.1     96.4
    B        38.0-38.4°C    denom        100.0    104.0
    B        38.0-38.4°C    num          2.0      5.0
    B        38.0-38.4°C    pct          2.0      1.8
    B        38.5-38.9°C    denom        105.0    100.0
    B        38.5-38.9°C    num          1.0      3.0
    B        38.5-38.9°C    pct          1.0      3.0
```

where _n in the numeric columns is the treatment occurence, there could be 500 treatments for some visits, how can this be handled efficiently without having to spec _1 as the first pivotted column, _2 as the second pivotted column,...,_n as the last pivotted column?

Thanks

Comment: Do you really want 500 columns in the output? Is this going to be meaningful, i.e. are people really going to read all 500 columns? By efficiently are you referring to the performance of the query or you not having to write out the columns, e.g. `PIVOT (MAX(Value) FOR Treatment IN ([1], [2], [3], ...[n]) AS pvt` - If there are only 3 treatments should there only be three columns?

Answer (score 6):

In order to get the result you want, you are going to have to unpivot your `denom`, `num`, and `pct` columns and then pivot the `treatments`. To unpivot the columns you can use `CROSS APPLY` or even `UNPIVOT` - this converts those multiple columns into multiple rows:

```
select t.visit, t.temperature, t.treatment,
  name,
  val
from yourtable t
cross apply
(
  select 'denom', denom union all
  select 'num', num union all
  select 'pct', pct
) c (name, val)
```

See [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6c614/1). Then you apply the PIVOT:

```
select visit, temperature, name, [1], [2]
from 
(
  select t.visit, t.temperature, t.treatment,
    name,
    val
  from yourtable t
  cross apply
  (
    select 'denom', denom union all
    select 'num', num union all
    select 'pct', pct
  ) c (name, val)
) d
pivot
(
  max(val)
  for treatment in ([1], [2])
)piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6c614/3).  Now the above code would require you to write out all of your `treatment`, if you have an unknown number then you would need to use dynamic SQL. Dynamic SQL creates a string that is then executed:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(treatment) 
                    from yourtable
                    group by treatment
                    order by treatment
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT visit, temperature, name,' + @cols + ' 
            from 
             (
                select t.visit, t.temperature, t.treatment,
                  name,
                  val
                from yourtable t
                cross apply
                (
                  select ''denom'', denom union all
                  select ''num'', num union all
                  select ''pct'', pct
                ) c (name, val)
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(val)
                for treatment in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

exec sp_executesql @query;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6c614/5). These both give:

```
| visit | temperature |  name |    1 |    2 |
|-------|-------------|-------|------|------|
|     A |       <38°C | denom |  101 |  100 |
|     A |       <38°C |   num |   98 |   97 |
|     A |       <38°C |   pct |   97 |   97 |
|     A | 38.0-38.4°C | denom |  103 |  100 |
|     A | 38.0-38.4°C |   num |    2 |    1 |
|     A | 38.0-38.4°C |   pct |  1.9 |    1 |
|     A | 38.5-38.9°C | denom |  100 |  102 |
|     A | 38.5-38.9°C |   num |    1 |    4 |
|     A | 38.5-38.9°C |   pct |    1 |  3.9 |
|     B |       <38°C | denom |  101 |  104 |
|     B |       <38°C |   num |   89 |   96 |
|     B |       <38°C |   pct | 88.1 | 96.4 |
|     B | 38.0-38.4°C | denom |  100 |  104 |
|     B | 38.0-38.4°C |   num |    2 |    5 |
|     B | 38.0-38.4°C |   pct |    2 |  1.8 |
|     B | 38.5-38.9°C | denom |  105 |  100 |
|     B | 38.5-38.9°C |   num |    1 |    3 |
|     B | 38.5-38.9°C |   pct |    1 |    3 |
```

Comment: Didn't know you could use CROSS APPLY to UNPIVOT... Obviously it works as I see from the SQL Fiddle. Is there any reason you didn't use UNPIVOT? Are there any benefits from using CROSS APPLY instead of UNPIVOT?

Comment: @TT. At this point it's just habit to use CROSS APPLY because when you have to unpivot columns in pairs it is much easier that unpivot. Plus if you have different datatypes, you can easily convert/cast them in the CROSS APPLY instead of having to use a subquery but as you can see UNPIVOT works the same --http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6c614/9

Comment: Oh small error in the UNPIVOT example: Has to be `UNPIVOT(val FOR name IN(denom,num,pct))`.

Comment: @TT. Yup, see why I prefer CROSS APPLY - fixed my comment above and the link